# Busboy doesn't work with async/await in azure function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, busboy

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  const name = context.bindingData.name;
  contractAccount = await near.account(contractName)
  switch (name) {
        case 'get_sale':
            get_sale_func(context, req);
            break;
        default:
            break;
}

function get_sale_func(context, req) {
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        log('Done parsing form!');
        context.res = {
            status: 200, 
            body: { result: "done" }
        };
    });
    busboy.write(req.body, function() {});
}
```

It does not return this response.

```
context.res = {
  status: 200, 
  body: { result: "done" }
};
```

[image]

But if I comment on this code `contractAccount = await near.account(contractName)` of line 3, it works.
[image]

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`Await` expressions make **promise-returning function**s behave as though they're synchronous by suspending execution until the returned promise is *fulfilled* or *rejected.*

In your case try to return Promise and try catch block to handle exception.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
try{
        const name = context.bindingData.name;
        contractAccount = await near.account(contractName) 
        switch (name) {
        case 'get_sale':
            get_sale_func(context, req);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    log.Info($"Exception found {ex.Message}");
}
}
function get_sale_func(context, req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
            busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
        });
        busboy.on('finish', function() {
            log('Done parsing form!');
            context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: { result: "done" }
        };
        resolve(context.res)
    });
    busboy.write(req.body, function() {});
    resolve(req)
    });
}
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944356/async-azure-function-app-not-awaiting-as-expected)

Comment: `await` does not halt execution of Azure Function using Node.js.  Example:  `const requestData = await req.json(); context.log("AAA"); context.log(requestData); context.log("BBB"); context.log("CCC"); context.log("DDD");`  The logs will appear in whatever order they like.  How to access `req.body` is not demonstrated in the official documentation, it says what methods *should* work, but provides no code to demonstrate it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4#http-request

Answer (score 1):

This worked. Just wrap the busboy section in Promise.

```js
async function nft_tokens_for_owner_func(context, req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let owner_id;
    const busboy = new Busboy({
      headers: req.headers
    });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      file.on('data', function(data) {
        files.push({
          fieldname,
          mimetype,
          data
        });
      });
      file.on('end', function() {});
    });
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
      if (fieldname === 'owner_id') {
        owner_id = val;
      }
    });
    busboy.on('finish', async function() {
      log('Done parsing form!');

      try {
        const tokens = await account.viewFunction(contractName, 'nft_tokens_for_owner', {
          account_id: owner_id,
          from_index: '0',
          limit: 100
        });
        context.res = {
          status: 200,
          body: {
            result: tokens
          }
        };
        context.done();
      } catch (e) {
        context.res = {
          status: 500,
          body: {
            result: e.message
          }
        };
        context.done();
      }
      resolve(true);
    });
    busboy.write(req.body, function() {});
  });
}
```